# function search select oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, function

i have a function like this,

```
create or replace procedure carinamapekerjaan (kode number) as
        pekerjaan varchar(50);
    begin
        select job_id as NAMADEP_141510926 into pekerjaan
        from employees where employee_id=kode;
        dbms_output.put_line (pekerjaan);
    end;
```

when i run, the result is like this
[image]

how to display title alias to NAMADEP_1411510926
[image]

Comment: Why don't you declare this as a `FUNCTION RETURN VARCHAR` instead of `PROCEDURE`? The you could just `return pekerjaan;` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `REFCURSOR` instead of `dbms_output.put_line()`

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Carinamapekerjaan (kode  NUMBER,
                                               c_emp OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
  pekerjaan VARCHAR(50);
BEGIN
    OPEN c_emp FOR
      SELECT job_id AS NAMADEP_141510926
      FROM   employees
      WHERE  employee_id = kode;

END;  
/

VARIABLE x REFCURSOR;
EXECUTE carinamapekerjaan(&inputkode,:x);
Enter value for inputkode: 101

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

PRINT x;

NAMADEP_141510926
------------------------------
AD_VP
```